# Create Picklist Values by workflow update

Tags: custom-object, workflow, picklist, account, dependent-picklist

Can I create picklist values dynamically by Workflow updates?

In a custom object picklist values need to be populated with Account Names dynamically after creation of an Account.

Please let me know this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: no, this is not possible by workflow updates.

In order to do this, you will need to write an APEX trigger that updates the object metadata. This is described e.g. here: [Adding values to a picklist using apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49057/adding-values-to-a-picklist-using-apex)

Alternatively, if the picklist only needs to be shown on a Visualforce page, you could generate the picklist values there dynamically upon loading the page. This is described in many online examples, e.g. here:
http://www.forcetree.com/2009/06/dynamically-add-values-to-picklist.html