# Can we add LookUp relation between custom object and custom metadatatype

Tags: apex, custom-object, workflow, custom-metadata

-->Can we add LookUp relation between custom Object and custom Metadata type?

--> My second question is, is it possible to create a picklist field with empty values and then we need to add picklist values dynamically using apex?

**Scenario :**

In my org, we have a custom Metadata type and we need to pass these records to the custom object. How can I proceed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. We cannot create the lookup relationship between custom object and custom metadatatype. Alternate approach can be creating a field and storing the record id as text(not recommendable approach).
2. Yes it is possible to add picklist values dynamically using apex.
   Kindly refer this [Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49057/adding-values-to-a-picklist-using-apex)